# Haproxy multi-line config

Tags: haproxy

Is it possible to split configuration arguments (in `haproxy.cfg`) onto multiple lines?

### Example

#### Current

```
frontend
     https-in bind :443 ssl strict-sni crt </path/to/cert1.pem> crt </path/to/cert2.pem> crt </path/to/cert3.pem> ...
```

#### Ideal

```
frontend 
    https-in bind :443 ssl strict-sni
        crt </path/to/cert1.pem>
        crt </path/to/cert2.pem>
        crt </path/to/cert3.pem>
        ...
```

#### Error when trying ideal

```
$ /usr/sbin/haproxy -c -V -f /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg
[ALERT] 343/210133 (25646) : parsing [/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:45] : unknown keyword 'crt' in 'frontend' section
[ALERT] 343/210133 (25646) : Error(s) found in configuration file : /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg
[ALERT] 343/210133 (25646) : Fatal errors found in configuration.
```

Comment: What problem do you encounter when you split the lines?

Comment: @JeroenHeier I get this error:
[ALERT] 343/210133 (25646) : parsing [/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:45] : unknown keyword 'crt' in 'frontend' section

Comment: (edit) Added configtest output to the question.

Comment: How are you generating the config file? If those means allow you could populate from variables or similar in your generation code to make writing the config easier. For example, we generate the config via a chef cookbook and thus don't set anything directly in the haproxy.cfg but instead through variables.

Comment: you can use  `crt-list` file name with all certs path.  It would be clean.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't do multiline syntax in the haproxy.cfg.

Take a look at the file format documentation:  https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.8/configuration.html#2.1

*Update:*

Thanks to the comment from [Venky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2921817/venky) I see that there is also the option to use `crt-list` which does provide an option for multi line pem file references. https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.8/configuration.html#5.1-crt-list

---

the improved config will be:

```
frontend 
    https-in bind :443 ssl strict-sni
    crt-list </path/to/list.txt>
        ...
```

the `list.txt`:

```
</path/to/cert1.pem>
</path/to/cert2.pem>
</path/to/cert3.pem>
```

Answer (score -1):

NO, you already known:
parameters continuation at new line is not supported.

If it's about long line readability,
maybe another workaround:

use `crt-base` to short the `crt <file_path>`
(by put them in same dir)
https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.8/configuration.html#crt-base

the conf will be looks like (still not very good):

```
global
   crt-base /etc/haproxy/crt_dir
   ...

...

frontend
     https-in bind :443 ssl strict-sni crt cert1.pem crt cert2.pem crt cert3.pem ...
```